# Is there a way to achieve circular joins in MariaDB ColumnStore since it is not supported?

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB ColumnStore and in ColumnStore, Circular joins are not supported.

In my database I have data regarding measurements sent from different countries and customers.

So for different roles I need to be able to filter the data inside the view.

So this is the structure I have right now

```
TABLE Measurements:

Country    Customer    Measurement
  a           1           150
  a           2           200
  b           3           250
```

I have a table which maps users to the roles

```
 TABLE UsersToRoles:

 Users      Roles 
   x        role1
   y        role2
```

I have a table which maps Roles to the data it is allowed to see

```
TABLE RolesToData

Roles  VariableType  VariableValue
role1  Country         a
role1  Customer        1
role1  Customer        2
role2  Country         b
role2  Customer        3
```

I created the following RoleView

```
 CREATE VIEW RoleView AS (
 SELECT UsersToRoles.User, Country, Customer FROM UsersToRoles.users AS User,  
 Country.VariableValue AS 'Country' FROM 
 ((UsersToRoles JOIN RolesToData Country ON (UsersToRoles.Roles = 
 Country.Roles AND Country.VariableType = 'Country'))
 JOIN RolesToData Customer ON (UsersToRoles.Roles = Customer.Roles AND 
 Customer.VariableType = 'Customer')))
```

Which returns the following VIEW

```
User    Country    Customer
 x        a           1  
 x        a           2 
 y        b           3
```

I would then like to join the Measurements table with the RoleView on both Country and Customer such as

```
  CREATE VIEW FinalView AS (SELECT measurement.* FROM measurement JOIN RoleView ON 
 (measurement.country = RoleView.country AND measurement.customer = RoleView.customer))
```

The problem is that MariaDB ColumnStore does not support circular joins.

Is there a work around to achieve a ciruclar joins without doing a circular join?

Perhaps through creating several views, and doing left or right joins on each view?

Would be really grateful if I found a solution to this.

*EDIT: UPDATE*

I did manage to find a quick fix, I am not sure about if this will have any severe impact or not.

If you use CONCAT on one of the join conditions it works.

```
  CREATE VIEW FinalView AS (SELECT measurement.* FROM measurement JOIN 
  RoleView ON 
  (measurement.country = CONCAT(RoleView.country,"") AND measurement.customer = 
  RoleView.customer))
```

This is based on a comment by Andrew in this thread

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL-1205

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly stated the simplies workaround is to replace a circular join condition with a functional condition that effectively does nothing to the arguments of this function.